After a fresh install of fedora 17, i have no root OR! even su - ability, how do i gain this?
Please, I have tried all related topics. I am an OLD SCHOOL Linux user RETURNING to it. Please I am not the slightest bit worried about destroying this or any mswin systems, I just want root access to my own system, is this even POSSIBLE in fedora 16/17 or has it been plugged so completely that even u guys can't explain me a way out??? PLEASE!

You need to explain what you're trying to do (and why...) , how you're about it, what is the expected result and what happens instead. The problem: want root access is ridiculously vague. And no matter how old your "old school" is, desktop Linux never had root login by default. Typically you'd be using sudo for anything needing elevated permissions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How did you install Fedora? Is it working normally? For what do you need root access? sudo doesn't work?

During the install process did you create an admin account? Please list, to the best of your ability, all of the steps you used installing Fedora, and rather than telling us "I have tried all related topics", tell us the specific things you have tried. We need to know what you've done and what you've already tried to help us understand the bounds of the problem and what not to suggest for solutions. Use the EDIT button to expand, improve, and clarify your problem.

It's a little hard to remember a decade back, but I think before the installer rewrite in F18/F19, it was possible skip both setting a root password and creating an admin (wheel group) account. That's probably what happened.
In this case, the easiest thing to do is:

boot a live USB image,
mount the root filesystem somewhere,
chroot to that
set the root password with passwd (or create an account in wheel — I think we had that set up with sudo powers by F14 -- if not, edit the sudoers file to taste)
unmount that filesystem
reboot (not with the live image)

Each of these can be explained in more detail, but if you want an easier path, it is probably "just reinstall". And, um, while you're doing that, please consider choosing a Fedora Linux version that has not been out of support for over a decade.
